# Xcode 9 GM - Export and Upload to App Store crashing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, xcode9

I'm trying to upload my app that uses ARKit (Unity build) to iTunes Connect for TestFlight distribution. While both exporting and uploading to app store processes from `Xcode` -> `Organizer` I see crash on "Stripping extended attributes for APPNAME.app".

I checked all configuration of bitcode and symbols on/off, signing automatically, manually. Deployment target of my project is iOS 10, as 11 cannot be set.
I also tried following steps from simillar thread (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83219) and added App Store 1024 icon to Images.xcassets.

Any ideas why Xcode is crashing?

Screenshot from just before the crash:
[image: Screenshot from just before the crash]

Crash report:

```
Process:               Xcode [10862]  
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-9b6.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode  
Version:               9.0 (13238.4)  
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13238004000000000~11  
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)  
Parent Process:        ??? [1]  
Responsible:           Xcode [10862]  
User ID:               501  


Date/Time:             2017-09-10 14:56:10.196 +0100  
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)  
Report Version:        12  
Anonymous UUID:        FD8390BC-9E7B-969D-15A2-22A8DBBD050D  




Time Awake Since Boot: 16000 seconds  


System Integrity Protection: enabled  


Crashed Thread:        17  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke  


Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020  
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY  


Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]  


VM Regions Near 0x20:  
-->  
    __TEXT                 0000000103625000-0000000103627000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode-9b6.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  


Application Specific Information:  
ProductBuildVersion: 9M214v  


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fffbb90634a mach_msg_trap + 10  
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fffbb905797 mach_msg + 55  
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffa6037434 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212  
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffa60368c1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361  
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fffa6036114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420  
5   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fffa5596ebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240  
6   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fffa5596cf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432  
7   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fffa5596b26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71  
8   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffa3b2fa54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120  
9   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffa42ab7ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796  
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit           0x0000000103eb58be -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390  
11  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffa3b243db -[NSApplication run] + 926  
12  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fffa3aeee0e NSApplicationMain + 1237  
13  libdyld.dylib                 0x00007fffbb7df235 start + 1
```

---

**Edit**

Running xcodebuild (through fastlane gym) produces the following:

```
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/z1/m155xvnn42s7xl7hfw3_8w5w0000gn/T/gym_config20170912-61009-190kutb.plist -archivePath '/Users/wert/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-09-12/towerar 2017-09-12 22.06.54.xcarchive' -exportPath /var/folders/z1/m155xvnn42s7xl7hfw3_8w5w0000gn/T/gym_output20170912-61009-42bo6w
2017-09-12 22:09:04.966 xcodebuild[62085:5372649] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/z1/m155xvnn42s7xl7hfw3_8w5w0000gn/T/Unity-iPhone_2017-09-12_22-09-04.966.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-09-12 22:09:21.584 xcodebuild[62085:5372649] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionPackagingStep: 0x7fc3c75f18b0>: <IDEDistributionPackagingStep: 0x7fc3c75f18b0>
2017-09-12 22:09:21.584 xcodebuild[62085:5372649] -[__NSCFString userInfo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3c74d72f0
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Uncaught Exception: -[__NSCFString userInfo]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc3c74d72f0
Stack:
0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
2   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
3   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
4   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
5   __55-[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _distributeArchiveAndExit]_block_invoke (in Xcode3Core)
6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _distributeArchiveAndExit] (in Xcode3Core)
7   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
8  0x0000000104d752af (in xcodebuild)
9   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Comment: Be sure you submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 9 GM

Comment: If you have Xcode 8.x installed, try deleting it

Answer (score 2):

I've had to uncheck all checkboxes and use manual managing signing, then it was possible to proceed in the wizard.

Comment: I've tried that, no luck. The issue was with xattr binary (as per accepted answer).

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. Are there more details on how to fix xattr on python?

Comment: I reinstalled macOS, it fixed the Python and xattr. I've tried reinstalling with homebrew, but it was still broken.

Comment: I tried to build the project on several computers, even with freshly installed OS. Didn't help. I've then reverted a failed attempt to include the HockeySDK and all of a sudden the crashes disappeared and things started to work. Interestingly the broken HockeySDK also caused Mercurial to not want to commit with the weirdest error messages. Both was fixed when i reverted to a previous commit.

Answer (score 1):

Does the xattr command line tool work? It's possible your python installation is damaged, or if you've replaced the installed xattr module then you may need to reinstall the system provided one.

Comment: Thanks for helping on Twitter, that fixed the issue! xattr was damaged by my previous python installations.

Comment: Please explain how to fix damaged xattr (if thats the issue). I am facing the same issue and nothing doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had been experiencing same frustating problem and it happen almost all day , Xcode 9 suddenly crashes in the middle of the archiving process, resulting in the same error report.

**@dangercheng** gave me insight about archive process in xcode 9, which is, it needs the **xattr** command , therefore I go check xattr command in my macbook and somehow **xattr** doesn't work. From the verbose message, it reveals that the error is related to file permission owned by folders/files inside **/Library/Python/2.7** . Somehow a user other than root has no right to write (w/ 2) on those files/folders.

From above facts I concluded that I need to change file permission in this case **chmod -R 775** and apply it to all folders and its content on **/Library/Python/2.7**. After that my **xattr** is running well and my Archive process in Xcode 9 is running smoothly, experiencing no crash.

Thanks for all of you guys

Comment: Was having issues with xattr and wasn’t able to reinstall. I’m submitting archived app with Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to permissions issues with python.

When running **xattr** from terminal I had the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/cb/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt'

Taking a look inside the **/Users/cb/Library** folder I found that all of the folders were owned by **cb:staff** (my currently logged in user and group) but the **/Users/cb/Library/Python** folder was owned by **root:wheel**

Running the following will eliminate the error:

> **sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Users/$USER/Library/Python**

After the **sudo chown** you can run **xattr** again to verify. There should be no errors or other output from the **xattr** command.

Comment: or:  sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Library/Python

Answer (score 0):

Probably not your fault but do file a bug with Apple. But when the Xcode uploader fails for any reason try the good ol' Application Loader:

`Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app`

Comment: To use the Application Loader you need to have `ipa` first, and exporting doesn't work :(

Comment: Oy. Did you try the usual clean build folder, reboot, etc?

Comment: I have raised the bug with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

run 'xattr' command in mac terminal，if result like bellow：

```
python version 2.7.10 can't run /usr/bin/xattr.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/xattr-2.6 (uses python 2.6)
/usr/bin/xattr-2.7 (uses python 2.7)

Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

you should creat a new soft link to '/usr/bin/xattr-2.7'
run bellow commands:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm xattr
sudo ln -s xattr-2.7 xattr
```

this solve my problem!

Comment: Same here. I got the solution, please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503257/xcode-9-crash-during-uploading-app-to-app-store/46741881#46741881

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem following @dangercheng's answer.
I upgraded my python to python 3.6 two days ago.And it seems that the xattr command was executed under python3.6 .
However, when I execute xattr in terminal.

`File "/usr/bin/xattr", line 31
    continue
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Something bad happened!
So I edit the source code of xattr.

`for i in g:
    vers = vpat.search(i)
    if vers is None:
       continue //add 4 space
    sys.stderr.write("%s (uses python %s)\n" % (i, i[vers.start():vers.end()]))
    n = 1`

```
python version 3.6.3 can't run /usr/bin/xattr.  Try the alternative(s):

(Error: no alternatives found)

Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```
another error!

I guess the xattr command should judge the version of python and execute suitable codes and the code of python3 contains some error.
Finally I change the default version of python to python2.7 and replace softlink of xattr to xattr-2.7. It works.
Attention, when xcodebuild execute xattr command the path of python was "/usr/bin/python".
The path "/usr/bin/python" was softlink too.
So, I resolved this problem following this step.
Step1:

`cd /usr/bin`

Step2:

`sudo rm python
sudo ln -s python2.7 python`

Step3:

`sudo rm xattr
sudo ln -s xattr-2.7 xattr`

If you can not found python2.7 under "/usr/bin", please find another suitable python path such as "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7" etc.