# Xcode 9 crash during uploading app to App Store

Tags: xcode, crash, app-store, cocoapods

In my project the Xcode 9 crashes during uploading to App Store (or exporting to disk, it does not matter). I have found that it may be caused by cocoapods or some kind of external frameworks bug, because on my other projects which do not use cocoapods this bug does not happen. However why I created post about it here on stackoverflow is the question if anybody has a **temporary solution to solve this issue**?

Unfortunately it is not known when it will be fixed by Apple or cocapods...so...every help would be welcomed.
I have already reported this bug to Apple with the (shortened) log below.

```
Process:               Xcode [7494]  
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode  
Version:               9.0 (13247)  
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13247000000000000~26  
App Item ID:           497799835  
App External ID:       823595305  
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)  
Parent Process:        ??? [1]  
Responsible:           Xcode [7494]  
User ID:               501  


Date/Time:             2017-09-20 20:04:30.103 +0200  
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)  
Report Version:        12  
Anonymous UUID:        9D0C9FF5-77EB-F94F-67E5-634E39EAE67B  


Sleep/Wake UUID:       30F3DB44-C016-4799-AD07-A080AA633DE8  


Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds  
Time Since Wake:       1500 seconds  


System Integrity Protection: enabled  


Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke  


Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000007fcb5ab5718  
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY  


Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

This post was also posted on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87647).

Comment: Issue has been resolved in Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with **`Xcode 9`** for many days and having tried so many things icluding some mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145276/xcode-9-gm-export-and-upload-to-app-store-crashing). I ended up

1. Download and install **`Xcode 8.3.3`** ( Always keep the older version, lesson for life )
2. **Archive** the app with **`Xcode 9`**
3. Open **`Xcode 8.3.3`**, open **Organizer** and submit the app

This works. Good luck.

**Update:** **`Xcode 9.0.1`** and **`Xcode 9.1 beta`** doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: work for me to but still a strange solution, waiting for a better one

Comment: Issue has been resolved in Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem.

I have the same problem with Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004).

First of all, check your problem is exactly same as mine.

1. To do this, open Terminal and put 'xattr' command and Enter.
2. If you can see kinda 'Permission denied' error message, fortunately you are just same as mine.
3. Now you can solve the problem by putting this one line command.

`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/`

so you can do 'Upload to Appstore' or 'Export IPA'.